# Excel search and lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a case where I need to extract a Weight based on the Data Range. The problem is that I can only enter Data and not range. I have shown this in the image below. What I would like to do is to implement the formula mentioned, so that I get the correct Weight based on the Range. What methods are available for this, in Excel?

**Weight and Data Range**

[image]

Comment: Unclear. DataRange-Weight is background table, or it is real table on some sheet range which must be used in a formula?

Comment: ... and what result do you need for values above 20?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the formula below. It assumes that the 1st data is in `A1`. Drag it to fill the other cells. Data above 10 but less than 20 are given a weight of 3.

```
=IF(A1<=5,1,IF(AND(A1>10,A1<20),3,2))
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that works. I also tried below and that works too unless I had an oversight? =IF(A1>=11,3,IF(A1>=6,2,1))

Comment: `=1+(A1>5)+(A1>10)` is more simple. But it is possible that ranges table is some worksheet range, and the values may be altered. @PrasanthRajagopal - why you do not answer the question in comment?

Comment: @PrasanthRajagopal Your formula implies that everything above 11 will be weighted as 3 while you stated only values  less than 20.

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of issues are frequently handled with a lookup table.

Below, I hard-coded the table into the formula, but you can list it separately on the worksheet and refer to it by a range reference.

It provides good flexibility and ease of modification, should that be necessary.

For example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,{0,1;6,2;11,3;20,"undefined"},2)
```

[image]

**Data Table** *(to be used if you prefer)*

[image]

If you set up a separate table, you would use a formula like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,$F$5:$G$9,2)
```

if your table is in `F5:G9`